# How to move SharePoint from one AD to another AD in another domain

Tags: sharepoint-server, active-directory, forms-authentication

Am quite new to SharePoint Central Admin stuff. Though there are other similar quires already available like [Move AD](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203948/how-to-move-sharepoint-2013-from-one-ad-to-another)

Am not able to make it out completely.

Scenario:
SharePoint Version - SharePoint Server 2010

1. We have SharePoint backup (content databases) and other artificats.
2. The Backed up SharePoint has user profile service and FBA configured.
3. We want to move SharePoint env. to another AD in another domain.
4. The new domain name and AD name will be same as it was in other environment

Kindly Let know whether this an be done. If yes, kindly share steps for the same.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To migrate SharePoint to another domain, make sure you have followed the steps as below:

1. Check if the SharePoint Central Administration’s Application Pool is running under Network Service or using a Domain Account
2. Making SharePoint Server a member server of a Different Domain
3. Setting up Service Account Rights
4. Set SQL Permissions
5. Updating Service Account
6. Migrating User Accounts and security group

More information refer to the article [Migrating SharePoint Server from one domain to another](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sushrao/2011/12/02/sharepoint-migrating-sharepoint-server-from-one-domain-to-another/)